# Undefined variable: db_username with mysqli_fetch_array in while loop ( and if else statement comparision)

Tags: php, apache

I am learning PHP. I am working on a simple login system with procedural PHP. I am getting username/password from this form:

Form Code:

```html
<form action="includes/login.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="What is your username?" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input name="user_password" type="password" placeholder="Your password goes here" class="form-control" >
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button name="login" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Login
    </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </span>
</form>
```

And sending it to `login.php` where I check that information with the database.  Bear with me, I'm learning, so what I am trying to do is to redirect users to `index.php` if `$username` and `$password` doesn't match with `$db_username` and `$db_user_password`

After some researching on StackOverFlow I found that I need to use `<?php ob_start(); ?>` at the top of the file but it still won't work. It throws the following error when I log in with the wrong user and password.

I tested with multiple browsers, restarted apache/MySQL many times, saved all files multiple times.

[image]

Here's my code in login.php file:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php include "db.php"; ?>
 
<?php
 
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
 
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
    $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $user_password);
 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
    $fetch_username_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 
    if (!$fetch_username_query) {
        die("Fetch Username Query Failed" .  mysqli_error($connection));
    }
 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_username_query)) {
        $db_username = $row['username'];
        $db_user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $db_user_password = $row['user_password'];
        $db_user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
        $db_user_lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
        $db_user_role = $row['user_role'];
    }
 
    if ($username !== $db_username || $user_password !== $db_user_password) {
        header("Location ../index.php");
    } 
}
 
?>
```

My db.php file has this:

```
<?php
$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "";
$db['db_name'] = "cms";

foreach ($db as $key => $value) {
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (!$connection) {
    die("MySQL connection failed");
}

?>
```

Also here's a screenshot from my phpMyAdmin users table:

[image]

I am using XAMPP on Windows 10 (PHP 7.4)

PS: I'm learning Procedural PHP first (basics), I am not using prepared_statement as of now, I'm aware of it, will learn that later. My problem is with `undefined variable`. Thanks, team :)

Comment: Your query is returning zero rows, therefore `$db_username` and friends are never defined

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or some other learning resource? If so, could you provide details? Whatever it is, it is out-of-date and promotes bad practices for writing safe queries with the MySQLi extension. You should be using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Don't learn them later. They actually make things much easier

Comment: PS: I am learning how to drive a car with a blindfold on first. I'm not looking at the road as of now, I'm aware of it, will learn that later.

Comment: @miken32 I reckon it's more akin to learning to drive a car with the handbrake on. Sure, you might get somewhere but something's bound to break at some point and you'll generally move a lot slower than you could

Comment: @Phil its returning rows when I use the correct username and password. It returns all values from the database. 

What I wanted is if the form values don't match with DB values then redirect to some other page using if...else statement.

Comment: If those variables are undefined, then your query is not returning any rows

Comment: I got my solution, I was missing a simple colon (:) after Location in header()function. Now, it's fixed. Thanks, everyone for the exact help I was looking for.